# Can't release my action for submission: "App display name is required"

Tags: release, actions-on-google

I designed an "Action on Google" skill for Google Assistant. When I try to release it for submission, I get an error "App display name is required". Display Name in the invocation tab is set. German is the only active language (English has bee deleted)

Anyone had that problem before? Am I looking at the wrong "App Display name"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating this actions using Dialogflow, please delete the English language from the Language settings (click the gear icon next to the agent name, and choose language tab).

Comment: The English language in Dialogflow could indeed be the problem. But I can't delete it as it is listed as default language. But if worse comes to worst, I can export it, remove english in the JSON files and re-import it I guess....